# How can I load local HTML into my WebView?

Tags: swift, xcode, webview

I try to load a local HTML into my WebView. The problem is that apparently it can't find my file. (fires "File reading error" at my console) I put my HTML file just in a folder with the name "test" and put the folder at my desktop. Do you have an idea where I should put my folder and file into, so that my code can find them?

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    do {
        guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "testPage", ofType: "html", inDirectory: "test1")
            else {
                // File Error
                print ("File reading error")
                return
        }

        let contents =  try String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: .utf8)
        let baseUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
        webView.loadHTMLString(contents as String, baseURL: baseUrl)
    }
    catch {
        print ("File HTML error")
    }
```

And here I put my file into.

[image]

Comment: `Bundle.main.path(for...` expects the file in the **application bundle** in a folder `test1` in folder `Resources`.

Comment: When you added the HTML file, have you checked that the file is added to your target?

Comment: The simulator... or your device cannot access your desktop to load files. The file should be part of your applications bundle so that it is copied to the device with the rest of the apps resources

Comment: Ok thank you very much!